# NullReferenceException when initializing MVCxGridViewColumn with null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nullreferenceexception

At line 233 I get a NullReferenceException, how is that possible?

```
Zeile 231:            foreach (var str in array)
Zeile 232:            {
Zeile 233:                MVCxGridViewColumn found = null;
Zeile 234:                foreach (MVCxGridViewColumn col in myresults.allcolumns)
Zeile 235:                {
```

I can provide other code if needed, but I don't have a clue where this error might come from.

I changed the code to test where the error comes from:

```
Zeile 232:            string[] array3 = {"A", "B"};
Zeile 233:
Zeile 234:            foreach (var str in array3)
Zeile 235:            {
Zeile 236:                //MVCxGridViewColumn found = new MVCxGridViewColumn();
```

Now the NullReferenceException appears in line 234. But the array can not be null because of line 232, right?

Comment: `myresults` or `myresults.allcolumns` is probably null. You can add a watch in debug to verify this.

Comment: but the error is in line 233, before myresults is accessed.

Comment: no, I check that before the loop

Comment: It's pretty doubtful that the NRE is happening on the `MVCxGridViewColumn found = null;` line of code.

Comment: I doubt it too, that's why I am so confused. I added another piece of code.

Comment: It seems that actuall myresults was null. Thanks to @HenkMollema. So the error message simply was in the wrong line.